# How to exclude css to load from homepage alone in magento 2?

Tags: magento, layout, magento2

I want to add if condition in layout xml file to allow css to load in below scenarios.

1. To load css file only in home page alone.
2. To load css by devices(Desktop, mobile & tab)?

Please let me know how to add condition in layout xml file?

```
<head>
    <css src="fonts/Lato/lato.css" /> <!-- Should be loaded in website home page only -->
    <css src="css/styles-mobile.css"/> <!-- Should be loaded in mobile devices only -->
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

To load css file only on home page you need to do this things.

You can add below code in you custom theme

```
app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\cms_index_index.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <css src="fonts/Lato/lato.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>              
    </body>
</page>
```

And add `lato.css` into `app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\web\css\fonts\Lato`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - OP is asking about exclusion, not inclusion.

Comment: @user7290573 Please read the question first point what write there. 1.To load css file only in home page alone.
So I post this answer.

Comment: the question title says "exclude CSS" and the first thing he mentions is adding CSS conditionally.

Comment: But the description says, need to load file only for homepage.